# How to implement VR and AR functionality in Mobile

Tags: plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, virtual-reality, oracle-jet

I need to develop a hybrid mobile using Oracle JET with VR and AR functionality .Is there any plugins to to implement those functionality in Mobile.

Are there is any steps or procedure that has to be followed to implement this functionality.

Accelerated reader is some thing related to the video shown in this link.
https://youtu.be/hnnr0P3JIPY

Virtual Reality is default one,through which user can view the car functionality in VR device

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, what do you want to achieve exactly? What is your technology stack that you want to add VR/AR to? Which kind of VR/AR are you thinking about, any examples of some other apps do the same thing that you want to do? Because if it's a "how to make vr" question without specifics, I'm voting to close this as it will be both too broad and opinion based.

Comment: I have updated my question @KrzysztofBociurko.Can you check it now.

Comment: There are libraries like Vuforia for the AR part, but frankly rendering this kind of content in a glorified webview is a bad idea. This will work poorly or will take you way way too much time to develop. Probably both. Consider doing this in Unity.